get array of attributes for a fixture
The following fixture definition
  app_module_ids: [ categoryminors(:storage_and_inventory).id categoryminors(:production_flow).id ]
  app_modules: [ categoryminors(:storage_and_inventory).name categoryminors(:production_flow).name ]

are not generating the expected values, but either a nil  or the stringification of the fixture referenced when intercepting the fixture in the test:
id: 545248419, app_module_ids: [nil], app_modules: ["categoryminors(:storage_and_inventory).name categoryminors(:production_flow).name"]

Using, according to the API documentation for Fixture label interpolation,
  app_module_ids: [ ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:storage_and_inventory) %>  <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:production_flow) %> ]

will generate [ 987341623 ] an array with a single value. (there are more values, but for brevity here, they were removed; the result is always a single id value)
Alas, the API documentation does not provide the syntax for arrays of values.  How do these two fixture get properly set?
